# Django: can I make db queries async?

Tags: python, django

In my app I have a template that I wish to make it like a control center that would display a ton of information, so I have to make a ton of queries to grab that info.

So of course, the page is slow as heck and now I'm thinking how to fix this.
I thought about making indexes but I don't have the space for this. I already optimized my queries to the minimun waste possible but it still takes like 1:30 minutes to load the page.

I'm looking into assynchronous support on Django, but the version of Django I'm using doesn't seem to support (2.1).

Does anybody got any tip that could help me in this?

I didn't showed my code because I figured it's not nescessary, for this question is more abstract. It's not about my problem especifics but more about optimization in general.

Comment: Celery/Django Channels

Comment: Sounds more like a scaling problem.

Answer (score 1):

The best idea is to use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/).
Although it is not recommended, you can use python Thread Pools.
Something like this:

```
queries = {
    '1': query_1, # These are your queries.
    '2': query_2,
    '3': query_3,
    '4': query_4,
}
# Since queries are lazy in Django, they have not been evaluated, yet.

# creating a threadpool
pool = ThreadPool(processes=int(len(queries) * 0.5))
threads = dict()
results = {}
for key in queries.keys():
    threads[key] = pool.apply_async(lambda f: f, args=(queries[key], ))

# wait for all threads to finish
for key, item in threads.items():
    results[key] = item.get()
```

Now your queries are being evaluated asynchronously.